# kalman filter in R when restoring missing values

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, kalman-filter

I did not know, where it would be more correct to ask my question, on CrossValidate or on stakoverflow, but decided here. 
If I'm wrong, just let me know, I'll delete the post and create it on a stackoverflow.

The question: i load daily data so that they can be monthly aggregated, but before it, i delete the outliers

```
vpg=read.csv("C:/Users/synthex/Desktop/vpg.csv", sep=";",dec=",")  
#del outliers
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  y
}

new <- remove_outliers(vpg$Y)
vpg=cbind(new,vpg)
View(vpg)

#del NA from newdataset
vpg=na.omit(vpg)



#aggregate data by mean of every month
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library("lubridate")
mydat=vpg %>%
  group_by(yearMon = as.yearmon(dmy(date))) %>% 
  summarise(new = sum(new))

View(mydat)
#create time series object for next forecasting
w=ts(mydat$new,frequency = 12,start=c(2015,1)) 
w
```

So how can i use Kalman filter to restore the missing data? 
Now as you can see a just delete NA.But it's not right.

if it is needed, here the reproducible example

```
vpg=structure(list(date = structure(c(10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("02.02.2015", "03.02.2015", 
"04.02.2015", "05.02.2015", "06.02.2015", "07.02.2015", "09.02.2015", 
"10.02.2015", "11.02.2015", "12.01.2015", "12.02.2015", "13.01.2015", 
"13.02.2015", "14.01.2015", "15.01.2015", "16.01.2015", "17.01.2015", 
"19.01.2015", "20.01.2015", "21.01.2015", "22.01.2015", "23.01.2015", 
"24.01.2015", "26.01.2015", "27.01.2015", "28.01.2015", "29.01.2015", 
"30.01.2015"), class = "factor"), Y = c(200L, 50L, 100L, 50L, 
200L, 200L, 50L, 200L, 100L, 1000L, 1000L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 200L, 
30L, 50L, 100L, 1000L, 100L, 100L, 25L, 70L, 1600L, 200L, 1000L, 
150L, 100L, 200L, 1400L, 200L, 100L, 300L, 200L, 200L, 400L, 
150L, 30L, 40L, 200L, 100L, 60L, 100L, 600L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 
100L, 1000L, 200L, 300L, 100L, 400L, 160L, 160L, 400L, 400L, 
1000L, 100L, 300L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 3000L, 200L, 
100L, 300L, 300L, 30L, 200L, 200L, 40L, 200L, 250L, 1000L, 50L, 
100L, 200L, 2000L, 200L, 600L, 100L, 50L, 200L, 1000L, 200L, 
100L, 50L, 400L, 35L)), .Names = c("date", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-92L))
```

Comment: This question is better suited for CV. You need to have some model for the dynamics of the process to use the Kalman filter to estimate missing values. Incidentally, you also need a model for the dynamics to find outliers correctly. Your proposed method would require you to build both a model for the daily data (to detect/estimate outliers) and one for the monthly data (to forecast). An alternative may be to aggregate first, then build just one model. You also have to be careful about how you measure out-of-sample performance (forecasting already "fixed" outliers is cheating).

Comment: @ChrisHaug, can you show me on my data how to do correct in mu code?